# How to delete Meteor Users on client side?

Tags: angularjs, meteor, meteor-accounts

I'm using meteor ui twitter accounts. What I'm attempting to do is basically delete all the users from the Meteor collection when the button clear is clicked on. This is my code:

HTML File:

```
<div ng-controller="TweetsCtrl">
<meteor-include src="loginButtons"></meteor-include>
<ul>
    <br>
    <div ng-repeat="t in twitterAccs">
        <img src = "{{t.services.twitter.profile_image_url_https}}">
        <br>
        <i>@{{t.services.twitter.screenName}}</i>
        <br>
        <br>
    </div>
    <button ng-click="clearUsers()">Clear</button>
</ul>
```

JS File:

```
    if (Meteor.isClient) {
      angular.module('twitter-example',['angular-meteor']);
      angular.module('twitter-example').controller('TweetsCtrl',['$scope','$meteor',function($scope,$meteor) {
      $scope.twitterAccs = $meteor.collection(Meteor.users);

      $scope.clearUsers = function () {
        $scope.twitterAccs = $meteor.collection(Meteor.users.remove({}) );
        console.log("hello");
      }
  }]);
}
```

Comment: This is a very strange thing to do. You will need the [`insecure` package](https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/insecure) for deleting all the users to work from the client.  But then anyone can delete all the users!

Comment: Yeah, I know. I was just messing around, that's all. But thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume this is only for development purposes right? It would suck to allow a visitor to your site to delete all your users. The fact you have a nice button set up for it has me worried it's a feature!

The easiest way to do it is hook up a Meteor.method like

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.methods({
    clearUsers: function() {
      Meteor.users.remove({});
    }
  });
}
```

Then do a Meteor.call('clearUsers') where your console.log("hello") is. You can also run the call via the browser console, I do this setup sometimes instead of going directly to the db via the terminal.

You could also do it via allow deny rules (see: http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/allow), by default a rule is setup so a user can only edit their own profile object.

Lastly you could include the meteor package insecure (I assume you must have already removed it) which will allow anyone to edit any collections assuming you haven't set up any of the allow, deny rules mentioned above.

Comment: Yeah, its only for development purposes. Why doesn't it work right now? It doesn't seem like its even going to the function since the hello is not being shown on the terminal.

Comment: Ok well then the problem to fix is that if your click event isn't even firing. I tried your code and it seems ok. You have a <body ng-app="twitter-example"> right? Also the <div ng-controller="TweetsCtrl"> is closed properly (</div>)? I would just try to get the console.log('hello') to fire before anything else as that's the culprit. I haven't used angular before but was able to that bare minimum working with your code and a tutorial so I think it's a problem with something you have omitted from you code you provided